# Where can I download Liberation Font family for use on Windows 7?

Tags: libreoffice

To improve compatibility between Word and Writer, I would like to be able to show people how to install the Liberation Font family in Microsoft Word.

Does anyone know where I can download a legit/safe version? Is there an "official" download place for the Liberation Font family for use on Windows?

Comment: This is offtopic for Ask Ubuntu.  Please read the FAQ for what questions are on topic.  As yoru question does not pertain to Ubuntu, it is considered offtopic.

Comment: As an Ubuntu user who works with a bunch of Windows users, this discussion facilitates interoperability between our documents. Therefore I think it is actually informative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The Liberation(tm) Fonts is a font family which aims at metric
>   compatibility with Arial, Times New Roman, and Courier New. It is
>   sponsored by Red Hat.

You can find the latest version on the [liberation-fonts page](https://fedorahosted.org/liberation-fonts/). Download the **„Binary (ttf)”** file. It is currently at version [1.07.2](https://fedorahosted.org/releases/l/i/liberation-fonts/liberation-fonts-ttf-1.07.2.tar.gz).

After downloading the tar.gz package you might need an unpacking tool (eg. [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)) on Windows.

The archive contains the following True Type (TTF) fonts:

```
LiberationMono-BoldItalic.ttf
LiberationMono-Bold.ttf
LiberationMono-Italic.ttf
LiberationMono-Regular.ttf
LiberationSans-BoldItalic.ttf
LiberationSans-Bold.ttf
LiberationSans-Italic.ttf
LiberationSansNarrow-BoldItalic.ttf
LiberationSansNarrow-Bold.ttf
LiberationSansNarrow-Italic.ttf
LiberationSansNarrow-Regular.ttf
LiberationSans-Regular.ttf
LiberationSerif-BoldItalic.ttf
LiberationSerif-Bold.ttf
LiberationSerif-Italic.ttf
LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf
```

Answer (score 1):

Info: https://www.redhat.com/promo/fonts/

Download: https://fedorahosted.org/liberation-fonts/